# Could you please help me in verifying if the calculation of entropy in the given question is correct?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I am trying to solve all of the parts of [problem no. 3](https://discuss.d2l.ai/t/information-theory-potential-issue-with-part-3-of-3rd-exercise-in-the-section-18-11-7/721/3) given in the following image - 
[image]
My solution to each part is as follows:-

1. Every character out of of 44 characters is equally probable.
   Let $X$ be an $r.v.$ such that $p(X=x_i) = \frac{1}{44}, i = 1 \ldots 44 $
   $H(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^{44}p(x_i)\log_{2}(p(x_i))$
   $= -p(x_{1})\log_{2}(p(x_{1})) -p(x_{2})\log_{2}(p(x_{2})) \ldots p(x_{44})\log_{2}(p(x_{44}))$
   $= -\frac{1}{44}\log_{2}(\frac{1}{44}) - \ldots -\frac{1}{44}\log_{2}(\frac{1}{44})$
   $= -\log_{2}(\frac{1}{44})$
   $= \log_{2}(44)$
   $= 5.45$
2. Every word out of of 2000 words is equally probable and every word has 4.5 words on average.
   Let $Y$ be an $r.v.$ such that $p(Y=y_i) = \frac{1}{2000}, i = 1 \ldots 2000 $
   $H(Y) = -\sum_{i=1}^{2000}p(y_i)\log_{2}(p(y_i))$
   $= -p(y_{1})\log_{2}(p(y_{1})) -p(y_{2})\log_{2}(p(y_{2})) \ldots p(y_{2000})\log_{2}(p(y_{2000}))$
   $= -\frac{1}{2000}\log_{2}(\frac{1}{2000}) - \ldots -\frac{1}{2000}\log_{2}(\frac{1}{2000})$
   $= -\log_{2}(\frac{1}{2000})$
   $= \log_{2}(2000)$
   $= 10.96$
   Hence, the entropy per character is: $\frac{H(Y)}{4.5} = 2.44$

Are the above solutions correct? If yes, can someone please help me find the entropy for the 3rd part? Thanks

Comment: Please don't post unsearchable pictures.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: I think your answers are correct. I can not figure out what really is the perplexity. It is not well defined. It seems they suppose the letters within a word are independent from each other (though the model is said to be high quality).

Comment: @ArnaudMégret, yes that seems to be assumption made in this definition of perplexity. However, while searching the internet, I found that the definition of perplexity is quite different from the one presented over here. Anyways, I guess this the definition that we need to go with for this problem.